# Exported Sql code gives error when runing

Tags: mysql

I have a sql function code which i exported from other db. But when i run it gives error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

My sql code is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getCOGS`(pItemId BIGINT) RETURNS float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  declare vRet FLOAT;
  SET vRet = 0.00;
   SELECT SUM(d.quantity*d.unitPrice) / SUM(d.quantity) INTO vRet
    FROM transaction_detail d
    INNER JOIN transaction t ON (t.componentId = d.transactionId AND t.`type` = 'PURCHASE')
    WHERE d.itemId = pItemId AND d.`type` = 1 AND d.accountId = 12;
  RETURN vRet;
END
```

Comment: [tag:sql-server] is a specific SQL database product from Microsoft. Neither your syntax nor the error message seem to relate to that product. I'd suggest you [edit] your question and re-tag it with the correct tag - which appears to be [tag:mariadb]

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:it seems he exported from mariaDB and asking how to change it ,so that it can run on SQLServer

Comment: @TheGameiswar - the *error message* mentions mariadb. So that seems to be the destination server. I can't talk to the source server but the script doesn't match SQL Server syntax. So at the moment, I don't believe that SQL Server is either the source nor the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the delimiter.
Try this

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getCOGS`(pItemId BIGINT) RETURNS float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  declare vRet FLOAT;
  SET vRet = 0.00;
   SELECT SUM(d.quantity*d.unitPrice) / SUM(d.quantity) INTO vRet
    FROM transaction_detail d
    INNER JOIN transaction t ON (t.componentId = d.transactionId AND t.`type` = 'PURCHASE')
    WHERE d.itemId = pItemId AND d.`type` = 1 AND d.accountId = 12;
  RETURN vRet;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

The DELIMITER statement changes the standard delimiter which is semicolon ( `;`) to another ( here `|`).

After your query, you can set it back to `;`